# how to recognise pack of a command

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

How can I recognise in ubuntu from which package was command installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg -S filename` will find the package that filename came from. Use the full path.  Searching for `/usr/sbin/apache2` will find just that file, but searching for `apache2` will give a long list.

To find the full path of a command use which as in `which apache2`.

You can also search the `.list` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. This directory also lists the confiration files in the `.confiles` files.  File names consist of the package name with a extension indicating the contents.  This is likely the directory that the dpkg searches.

Comment: Now that's the way to do it. I realize now that I should probably learn APT a bit more even though I seldom need to use it for more advanced purposes.

Comment: @cmbrnt I usually just search the directory, as it saves me running man dpkg to find the right switch.

Comment: If it's a file that's not in the path, `which` won't find it. You could use `locate` (or `find`) to find it in that case.

Comment: `dpkg -S $(which filename)` should work if you only know the short filename and not the full path, at least for an executable program.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this (sometimes) is to run "`apt-cache search <command>`", which sometimes displays the package name. Don't quote me on this, but I think this depends on the information given in the verbose description of the package in the APT-repository. It might be the names of the files in the .deb-package, but that's less likely.

This is the method I use at least, and it works most of the time. Otherwise, Google usually helps.